# how to change the values of pickerviews triggered by event

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I want to create my own datepicker with a uipickerview, where I can choose between 9999 B.C. and 2015 A.D. I use a UIPickerview with more then one component. My first 4 components contain only numbers 0-9.
Component 1 holds the thousand of years (1000,2000 usw...).
My last component contains {A.D. & B.C.). Depending on the last Picker I would change the values of component 1, which represents the thousender of the years. In case the user has choosen "A.D." in the last component, it should not be possible to choose 3-9 in the first component.

How to achieve this ?

Code:

```
      func showDatePicker(){
            var datePicker=UIPickerView()
            datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(1, 100, 250, 162)
            datePicker.delegate=self
            datePicker.dataSource = self
            datePicker.tag = 1
            datePicker.backgroundColor=UIColor.orangeColor();
            datePicker.selectRow(180, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            self.view.addSubview(datePicker)

        }
        func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
            return 5
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {


            println("evaluate amount of components");

            if component == 0{
                return 10
            }else if component == 1{
                return 10
            }else if component == 2{
                return 10
            }else if component == 3{
                return 10
            }else if component == 4{
                return 2
            }

            return 10
        }

        func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

            if component == 0{
                return "\(row)"
            }else if component == 1{
                return "\(row)"
            }else if component == 2{
                return "\(row)"
            }else if component == 3{
                return "\(row)"
            }else if component == 4{
                if(row==0){
                    return "A.D.";
Here I like to limit the values of component 1 to {0,1,2}, because
the year should not go over the year 3000 A.D.
                }else{
                    return "B.C.";

                }
            }else{
                return "?";
            }
        }
```

** UPDATE MY SOLUTION **

I don't know if this is best practice, but I solved it as follow:
depending on the year I show different amount of values in the pickerview:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {


        println("evaluate amount of components");

        let iYear=DataContainer.sharedInstance.iYear;
        if(iYear > 0){

            if component == 0{
                return 3;
            }else if component == 1{
                return 10;
            }else if component == 2{
                return 10;
            }else if component == 3{
                return 10;
            }else if component == 4{
                return 2;
            }else{
                return 1;
            }

        }else{
            if component == 0{
                return 10
            }else if component == 1{
                return 10
            }else if component == 2{
                return 10
            }else if component == 3{
                return 10
            }else if component == 4{
                return 2
            }else{
                return 1;
            }

        }

    }
```

When I change my last component (5), which presents "A.D." or "B.C." I just refresh the pickerview:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
...
else if component == 4{
            if(row==0){
                if (iYear < 0 ){
                    //DataContainer.sharedInstance.iYear = -iYear;
                    datePicker.reloadAllComponents();
                }
                return "A.D.";
            }else{
                if (iYear > 0 ){
                    //DataContainer.sharedInstance.iYear = -iYear;
                    datePicker.reloadAllComponents();
                }
                //datePicker.reloadAllComponents();
                return "B.C.";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you have to react to the change in the 5th component. In `pickerView(didSelectRow:inComponent)` handle a change from or to `A.D.`. Perhaps maintain a flag that indicates which one is selected.

Then call `reloadComponent()` or `reloadAllComponents` to update the picker view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just fount it out myself. Perhabs you can review my Update in the question to confirm this is best practise ? Thanks.

Comment: Looks OK ;-). Sometimes it helps writing out the question to have a clear understanding of the problem.

Comment: Yes exactly. Or probably I am sometime a bit too impatient :-) I hope the question will help others too.